# Discover Swing Component Variable Name At Runtime

Tags: java, swing

I'm not sue if this is even possible, but I have a Swing application that has on the order of four dozen different labels that I'm having to track down bugs in, an application that I didn't initially write, variables that aren't statically defined in the source, and I'm having trouble tracking down precisely what label corresponds to the variable name in the source code.

Are there any sorts of plug-ins or applications that can tell you information about Swing GUI objects while the application is running, including the variable name, if any, it is referenced by?

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly get the variable name of an object.

If you are using eclipse, you can create a [conditional breakpoint](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_set_a_conditional_breakpoint%3F) in the JLabel constructor that does something like,

```
this.putClientProperty("creation stack trace", new Exception());
```

This will let you see the stack trace (and creation line number) of every JLabel created.

Answer (score 1):

If I were you, I'd do it like this:

- open src.zip from java jdk and extract JLabel.java. Place it in your project.
- modify that class:

  - add a field with type Throwable, and at the end of every constructor write a `new Throwable()` to it.
  - at the end of every constructor add new mouse click listener to the component. The handler doesn't have to do anything, it's just so you can place breakpoint in it.

Now when you run your app your modified JLabel will take precedence over standard JDK one. When you want to find a point in code where some label was created, set breakpoint in the added event handler, click that label, and when debugger pauses, examine the stack in added Throwable field.

Remember to remove your custom JLabel after debugging is finished and not ship it in production code, as creation of Throwable() in each JLabel will have negative performance consequences.

Comment: +1 Good solution if you can't access the source code of the application. But I think he can, so I would prefer using a GUI debugger as mentioned in my post.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to debug and see which object belongs to which component in the GUI, I would recommend using [Swing Explorer](http://www.swingexplorer.com/) for debugging.

You can also extend JLabel, add debugging functionality to it and replace all JLabels in the code by your new "debugging" label.